# Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 4): need struct type but got string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written the below case class and creating a dataset based on that.

```
 case class seqAccountData(customerId: String, accountId: String, balance:Long, newBalance: Long, account: Seq[AccountData])

  val seqAccountDf: Dataset[seqAccountData] = accountDS
    .selectExpr("customerId", "accountId", "balance", "newBalance",
      "array(customerId, accountId, balance) as account").as[seqAccountData]
```

The issue I'm facing is Can't extract value from lambdavariable(MapObject, StringType, true, 4): need struct type but got string.

Tried replacing array with Seq, List everything but not working. Please suggest some alternate approach

Comment: can you please provide a full example and more stack trace?  It could be seqAccountData is not defined as a top level class - it cannot be defined within another class, function or object